# How can i get an error on specific response code natively?

Tags: node.js, requestjs

Now this method throws an error if the response code is not 2xx (learned experimentally)

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await request({
      uri: 'http://httpbin.org/status/201',
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    });
    console.log(response.statusCode); // we here
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // i want to be here if statusCode !== 200
  }
})();
```

Maybe there is some parameter or another package that can do something i want?

Answer (score 0):

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await request({
      uri: 'http://httpbin.org/status/201',
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    });
    console.log(response.statusCode); // we here
    if(response.statusCode !== 200){
        //do your stuff here instead??
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // i want to be here if statusCode !== 200
  }
})();
```

how about this

Comment: I mean, you are going to write custom code in the catch statement anyway so why not in that if statement instead?

Comment: Why do you want to enter in the catch statement then?

Comment: Because for my tasks only 200 there is a positive response code in other cases I want to get the same error structure in the catch block for further processing